# Why does Libgdx setup.jar keep telling me it cannot find android sdk?

Tags: android

I downloaded the Libgdx set file here: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html.  I have used it before with Eclipse but this version keeps telling me it cannot find the Android Sdk.  I am pointing it to Android->sdk->platform-tools where there is an adb.exe file.  My guess after a couple hours of trying is that this is not the location it is looking for.  I have been searching and getting part answers but cannot get the setup to see sdk.  Can someone tip me off on what I am doing incorrect?

Thanks,
Terry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put Android->sdk without `platform tools`.
I hope it helps,
cheers,

 staticcasty